# iReport Chart Stacked and Grouped bar

Tags: ireport

Is possible to create a Grouped and Stacked Chart like this in iReport?

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartStackedBarChartDemo4.htm

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, you can do stacked bar charts but you cannot group bars with iReport alone.

You can however, use chart customizers [like this](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/chart-customizers-2/) or otherwise implement any JFreeChart feature with code.

Or if you don't mind missing the spaces, for the category expression use

```
"Product " + $F{ProductNum} +  " " + new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy").format($F{Day})
```